# How to change all values of a dataframe column in Spark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

So, I have a dataframe:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgA04.png)

I want to replace each Iris-setosa to 0, each Iris-versicolor to 1, and each Iris-virginica to 2 in Species column using pyspark. How to do it?